# change some tinymce behaviour (javascript)

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Hi everybody 
I am using the tinymce format dropdown to apply custom styles to html elements. This is for users without html knowledge
One annoying thing for me is that when a user klicks at different styles they all get added and something like this may happen

```
<div class="floatleft floatright positionup positiondown">
```

In order to prevent this I searched for the responsible code which is in editor_template.js (compressed) but visible in editor_template_src.js

Is there maybe a way to rewrite this piece of javascript so that each applied style replaces the former?

```
_createStyleSelect : function(n) {
            var t = this, ed = t.editor, ctrlMan = ed.controlManager, ctrl;

            // Setup style select box
            ctrl = ctrlMan.createListBox('styleselect', {
                title : 'advanced.style_select',
                onselect : function(name) {
                    var matches, formatNames = [];

                    each(ctrl.items, function(item) {
                        formatNames.push(item.value);
                    });

                    ed.focus();
                    ed.undoManager.add();

                    // Toggle off the current format
                    matches = ed.formatter.matchAll(formatNames);
                    if (!name || matches[0] == name)
                        ed.formatter.remove(matches[0]);
                    else
                        ed.formatter.apply(name);

                    ed.undoManager.add();
                    ed.nodeChanged();

                    return false; // No auto select
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if (!name || matches[0] == name)
    ed.formatter.remove(matches[0]);
else
    ed.formatter.remove(matches[0]);
    ed.formatter.apply(name);
```

Just a wild guess, haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This a lot of work to do, but it can be done.
I solved this issue writing a custom plugin and using a custom FormatterClass.
I suggest you try developing with `tiny_mce_dev.js` - this way you are able to track down problems to js classes.
Then you should have a look at the js-class `Formatter.js` and try to modify this one in order to fullfill your wishes.
The next step will be to save the mofied Formatter.js and make it part of your plugin, so that you can reset the real Formatter.js, cause i suggest not to change the tinymce core files.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Looks like a lot of learning for me. I'll check it out and see how far I can get.